# Access module method from Capybara node element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, module, capybara

I'm trying to move some of the Capybara selector inside a module helper.

```
module Helper
  def element
    page.all(:css, '.element_class')
  end

  def sub_element
    find('.sub_element_class')
  end
end
```

And my test is

```
scenario 'get the sub element'
  visit 'path'
  element.sub_element.click_button 'Button'

  expect(page).to have_content('something')
end
```

and I get a NoMethodError:

> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `sub_element' for Capybara::Node::Element:0x006fb54911ef88

but, if I use directly the method 'find' instead of my own method 'sub_element', everything works as expected.

```
element.find('.sub_element_class').click_button 'Button'
```

and I can't find in the documentation if it possible to use module's methods on Node Elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `self` to chain this methods.

```
module Helper
  def element
    page.all(:css, '.element_class')
    self # Add this
  end

  def sub_element
    find('.sub_element_class')
  end
end
```

[More info](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-guide-to-method-chaining/) about method chaining.